# When do HTML async scripts *finish* executing?

Tags: javascript, html, deferred-loading

There is a lot of documentation about how `async` and `defer` affect the timing of the loading and the start of execution of external scripts, but I can't find anything that mentions when the script *finishes* executing.

For instance, suppose the external script defines functions `one()`, `two()`, `three()`, and `four()`:

```
<head>
    …
    <script async="async" src="…"></script>
    …
</head>

<body>
    …
    <script> window.onload="one()" </script>
        …
    <script> two() </script>
</body>

<script> three() </script>

</html>

<script> four() </script>
```

The external script starts loading in parallel with the HTML, and then executes as soon as it's loaded.

I'm pretty sure that `two()` is unrealiable, as it *could* be undefined when it gets called, but I don't know about the others.

Are any of the functions guaranteed to be available when they are called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are *all* unreliable, except for the `onload()` invocation.

This page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Load script</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script async="async" src="script.js"></script>
    <script> one() </script>
</head>

<body onload="two()">
    <p>Test</p>
    <script> three() </script>
</body>

<script> four() </script>

</html>

<script> five() </script>
```

produces:

[image: error messages for 1, 3, 4, and 5, log entry for 2]

but everything works fine without the `async`:

[image: log entries for 1, 3, 4, 5, and 2]

I.e. you can be sure the async script has finished when the `onload()` happens, *but not before that*.

So in general, for async script loading:

- Nothing in the HTML can rely on the script's having been loaded.
- Nothing in the script can rely on anything in the HTML having been loaded.

That severely restricts the circumstances under which async scripts can be used.

The async scripts must not do anything other than defining functions, etc.
And those functions can't be used in the HTML until the processing has reached the `onload` stage.

```
<tag onclick="external_function()"> ... </tag>       <!-- works -->

<script> something = external_function() </script>   <!-- fails -->
```